# No longer receiving "String length exceeds maximum" in SOAP Callouts

Tags: apex, callout

We have a .NET SOAP web service called by an Apex class that returns very large strings. The class used to occasionally throw the error: "String length exceeds maximum". I just realized it isn't throwing the error in situations that it used to.

Does anyone know if Salesforce made changes behind the scenes to the code to make this limit much larger? It would have happened in one of the last 2 to 3 releases. Maybe the maximum size of callout increase from 3MB to 6MB?

If it is something to do with the string length limit, what did it get increased to?

Comment: The limit for a response is now: 6 MB for synchronous Apex or 12 MB for asynchronous Apex

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but isn't that a different error thrown?

Comment: On the string length limit, in execute anonymous `'x'.repeat(7 * 1000000);` produces "System.LimitException: String is too long".

Comment: Does the error come when doing a dml to salesforce? If yes, probably the length of the field which carries the string may have been increased. That could be a possibility.

Comment: @DanielHoechst - I was just answering the part of your question: 'Maybe the maximum size of callout increase from 3MB to 6MB'

Comment: @AsifK, the exception used to get thrown when deserializing the SOAP response.